# Represent antichains with efficient join and meet operations

Tags: java, performance, math, optimization, data-structures

### Some information

I am working on a program that works with basic sets and antichains.

[Antichains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain) are subsets of the powerset of a set so that no two elements (sets) in this subset are subset of another element (set) in this subset. For instance {{1},{1,2}} is not an antichain because {1} ⊆ {1,2}.

Some of the most important operations on antichains A and B can be defined as

1. a.join(b) = sup(a ∪ b)
2. a.meet(b) = sup({X ∩ Y | X ∈ a and Y ∈ b})

Where sup is the [supremum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) of an antichain, meaning the smallest antichain bigger than the given set.

#### Representation thus far

The basic set is represented by a `long`, bitarray-alike. This means that every element of the set is represented by a 1 in the bitarray. For instance the set {1,2,3} is represented by 7 (the bitarray 111) and the set {1,2,4} is represented by 11 (the bitarray 1011) and so on.

Now I wanted to lift this representation to represent the antichains in a similar way. This means I could represent the antichain {{1},{2,3}} as 1000010 in a bitarray, because the long storing the set {1} is 1 and for {2,3} it is 6 (the indices of the 1's in the bitarray).
Unless I find some better alternatives, I use the [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)-class to work with this bitarray, hoping to save some time over working with any `Collection<T>`.

I managed already to define and optimise most of the elementary operations stated before, but they were optimised in an older implementation, simply using a `TreeSet`, thus not optimised for working with the bitarray.

### My questions

1. My question now is whether BitSet is the optimal representation, knowing that these bitarray-representations double in size every time an element to the starting set is added. I also thought of `BigInteger` for instance, having the advantage to be comparable (something I also need).
2. Also I would like to know whether anybody already did something likely and knows how to implement the join and meet efficiently, using bitarray-properties.

Thanks in advance.

---

### Edit:

The code for my join and meet look like this, for the moment:

```
public AntiChain join(AntiChain ac) {
    AntiChain res = new AntiChain(this);
    for(int i = ac.bitset.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = ac.bitset.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
        res.addAndMakeAntiChain(new BasicSet(i));
    }
    return res;
}

public AntiChain meet(AntiChain ac) {
        AntiChain res = AntiChain.emptyAntiChain(this.getUniverse());
        for(int i = bitset.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = bitset.nextSetBit(i+1))
            for(int j = ac.bitset.nextSetBit(0); j >= 0; j = ac.bitset.nextSetBit(j+1)) 
                res.addAndMakeAntiChain(new BasicSet(j).intersection(new BasicSet(i)));
        return res;
    }

private void addAndMakeAntiChain(BasicSet x) {
    for(int k = bitset.nextSetBit(0); k >= 0; k = bitset.nextSetBit(k+1)) {
        BasicSet a = new BasicSet(k);                         //new BasicSet(7) = {1,2,3}
        if(a.hasAsSubset(x)) return;
        if(x.hasAsSubset(a)) bitset.set(k, false);
    }
    bitset.set(x.toIntRepresentation());                      //{1,2,3}.toLong() = 7
}
```

Comment: ZDDs perhaps? It looks like a set of sets anyway

Comment: I don't think it would improve much, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I wanted to lift this representation to represent the antichains in a similar way. This means I could represent the antichain {{1},{2,3}} as 1000010 in a bitarray, because the long storing the set {1} is 1 and for {2,3} it is 6 (the indices of the 1's in the bitarray).

This sounds wrong: What about `{{1, 64}}`. IIUYC the index is 2**63 + 1, way too big for a `BitSet`. If you want an optimized representation for this, consider some primitive long collection (trove4j, colt, hppc, ...).

> 3. In order to be able to compare my bitarrays, are there any more efficient ways to convert a BitSet to a BigInteger?

The most efficient way will surely be avoiding the conversion. A `BitSet` can be iterated (in both directions), so you can do a lexicographical comparison directly.

```
BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;
for(int i = theAntiChain.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = theAntiChain.nextSetBit(i+1))
    result = result.setBit(i);
return result;
```

This is extremely inefficient, you could create a `byte[]` instead, fill it, and use `new BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude)`.

Comment: I know it sounds strange to use this representation for general usability, but the program only works with sets that contain numbers from 1 to 12, causing no troubles for BitSet. Also I know very little about all these libraries. Are there any specific advantages over using (simple!) bitsets? PS: I compare my bitsets differently now :-)

Comment: @MrTsjolder Even with 12, you get an index over 1000, which sound wasteful and may be pretty inefficient. These libraries are just like regular collections but optimized for primitives. ++ Look at how many bits in your BitSet are used. If too few, a Collection will be more efficient.

Comment: I must admit at first I assumed BitSet would be implemented efficiently for the sparse case too (bad habit from working with Matlab). Could it be more efficient to implement BitSet myself? Something with an index-array and a minimal long-array? (I'll have a look at the libraries when I have some more time again...)

Comment: @MrTsjolder No, BitSet is dense. Sure, you could try to do it yourself. You probably need only a couple of operations, it should be pretty easy. But you need it to be ordered (because of the comparison), which makes it much harder (you need a tree or alike). Unless the comparison speed is unimportant...

Comment: comparison speed is important, but not the way how it is compared. I only need the comparison because I'm using existing code, putting the antichains in treesets. The only thing really needed, is that compareTo returns 0 when not equal. Thanks in any case for the nice answer. Btw: no ideas on how to do the meet/join?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can think of a better way of storing your antichains (still in BitSets). Currently, your sets will be pretty sparse -- high 0:1 ratio.

I'd just concatenate them. Each one is guaranteed to be less than `64` bits long since you are representing them with `long` values, so I'd do something like this

```
public static void put(BitSet antiChain, long value) {
    int len = antiChain.length();
    antiChain.clear(antiChain.size() - 1);
    len -= len % 64;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        if ((value & (1 << i)) != 0) antiChain.set(len + i);
    antiChain.set(antiChain.size());
}
public static long get(BitSet antiChain, int index) {
    long value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        if (antiChain.get(index * 6 + i)) value |= (1 << i);
    return value;
}
public static boolean contains(BitSet antiChain, long value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < antiChain.size() / 64; i++) {
        if (get(antiChain, i) == value) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

which does include one set bit at the end no matter what to make sure that the number of sets contained is explicit; i.e. so that `{} != {{}}`

For a concrete example, here's what would happen to `{{1},{2,3}}`. (Note that `s(n)` refers to the set that `n` refers to.

- `{{1},{2,3},{4,5}} = {s(0b10), s(0b110), s(0b110000)} = {s(2), s(6), s(48)}`
- The `put` function will encode this as `2*2^(64*0) + 6 * 2^(64*1) + 48*2^(64*2)` (where `^` represents exponentiation, not XOR).
- The `BitSet` representing this is `{1, 33, 64, 65, 66, 97, 98, 128, 132, 133, 164, 165, 256}`

Also, no matter how efficiently you convert a `BitSet` to a `BigInteger`, `compare` will still take place in `O(L)` time, where `L` is the length of your antichain in sets. You are probably better off

- If multiple comparisons per antichain: just calling `toLongArray()` and comparing the `long` values manually
- If one comparison per antichain: manually looping from high bit to low bit and checking.

Comment: I am aware of the sparsity, but as I don't seem to need antichains for sets with 9 elements very fast, I don't really bother about it. On the other hand, I'm having troubles understanding what you're doing. Could you maybe give an example? Now I have this feeling {{1},{2,3}} would be stored like 111 if you added {2,3} to {{1}} (just 'or' the bitarray representations for small sets) and I don't really see how this would work.

Comment: I'm losing it, I'm afraid. At first, I have this feeling you made some mistakes in representing {1} (0b01 = 1) and {4,5} (0b11000 = 24) if you wanted to use my representation for a set. Next I don't get what 2 + 6 * 2^64 + 48 * 2^128 does there (this is only `{1, 65, 66, 132, 133}`, not?). Third I don't see how this could be more efficient than representing {{1},{2,3},{4,5}} with the bitset `{1,6,24}` . PS: performing a meet or join operation on this doesn't seem quite straightforward either.